# Javascript: put GPS coords into var

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gps

I apologize but I'm not expert in JavaScript, I need to get Latitude and Longitude in a variable to track a route using Google Maps.

```
    function calcRoute() {
    var start = "position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude";
    var end = "<?php echo $la; ?>,<?php echo $lo; ?>";
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
```

This code works if I write

```
        var start = "12.3456789,12.3456789";
```

As you can see, using PHP to put end's coords works fine. I tried different ways to use position.coords.latitude into **end** var but I don't understand why "position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude" don't change in "12.3456789,12.3456789".

Note: I am sure position.coords.latitude and position.coords.longitude are filled correct because using an alert I can see the rights values.

Thanks for help...

Comment: can you just paste what exactly gets outputted in end var?

Comment: var end ="12.3456789,12.3456789";

Comment: What is `position.coords` ?  JS variable? if yes can you show how you define it and how is it assigned value?

Comment: It's html5 Geolocation... http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with concatenating variables to `string` in javascript. If `position.coords.latitude` or `position.coords.longitude` is a number (or it could be string, in this case it doesn't matter) to get a string like `"12.3456789,12.3456789"` from it you have to connect the variables using `+` operator.

So you should have:

```
var start = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
```

In your code.

**EDIT**

A working example:

```js
function geocode(){
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(calcRoute,function(error){
         alert("Geolocation does not work because:" + error.message);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function calcRoute(position) {
    console.log(position);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
                              
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var start = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    var end = "49.200147, 16.607560";
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }else{
        alert("Direction were not found:" + status);
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry&dummy=.js"></script>
<body onload="geocode()">
  <div id="map" style="height:400px; width:500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way but I tried lots of ways without find the right sintax.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try this code on your server. Remember to replace `var end = "12.3456, 12.3456";` with some meaningful values. There are also error callback in the code so if something goes wrong you will know why.

Comment: I put the URL of my test: http://localhost/www.parcheggi.info/metropark/gmaps2.php?id=8 as you can see (html source) the script do not fill the start var with "12.34567"...

Comment: Apologize me, use the URL without "localhost"... http://www.parcheggi.info/metropark/gmaps2.php?id=8

Comment: So what is the problem then? Everything seems to be working for me. It gets the directions object without problems.

Comment: You never mentioned that you also want to display the map. I thought you only want to get the directions object. Anyway, I have updated my code, now it also displays map. Try the code on your server.

Comment: Sorry but for me does not work http://www.parcheggi.info/metropark/gmaps2.php?id=8 . If I try on my S3 phone I receve an error message too (Direction were not found: ZERO_RESULTS) http://pho.to/AARNl

Comment: That's because Google can't find any route between where you are (Or where your mobile geolocation thinks you are) and the destination. For me it works perfectly. Enable GPS on your mobile, or try from some other location, or try from some other mobile device.

Comment: After lots of test I saw that is working with IE on Nokia Lumia but I don't see the map using Android Chrome or iPhone... unbeliveable! I have absolute no ideas why! http://www.parcheggi.info/metropark/gmaps.php?id=8